# Combining data points with overlaying grid

Tags: qgis

I have a map of Ireland with several data points on that map. I want to create a 10km x 10km grid on that map that colours in each grid square that contains a data point. So, if at least one data point lies inside a grid square, the square will be coloured in.

I'm very new to QGIS and still trying to understand the basics.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please define what "map" does mean in this context. Is it an image, or a PDF, or a shapefile, is it georeferenced or not, what is the resolution, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve the identification you need with some simple steps:

1. Create a grid
2. Calculate how many points there are in each square
3. Stylize accordingly

### Create a grid

[image]

Make sure you select "Rectangle", so it is actually a tiled space, not just a set of orthogonal lines.

[image]

### Calculate how many points there are in each square

Use the `Join attributes by location (summary)` tool as follows:

[image]

### Stylize accordingly

Now:

- double click on the just created layer (probably named `Joined layer`),
- under `Symbology` select `Rule based`
- add two rules
- in the first insert a rule like `"id_count" >0` (where `id` was the field I counted on my points layer). This means that the first rule only applies to square tiles with at least 1 point. Make it green, for example.
- in the second tick the `Else` button. This rule will match all other tiles (i.e. all tiles with 0 or points). Make it for example white or yellow.

[image]

### Result

[image]